# mongoDB search only last 6 digits

Tags: search, mongodb, find

Is there away to use find() to search for barcode that ends with the last digits 365478 I dont care what is in front

I thought something like this.

```
$db.find(array('barcode'=>*365478))
```

but that does not seem to work. am I missing something?

Comment: How do you store the barcode? Integer? Or string? If string, you can use regular expressions.

Comment: string "barcode": "4585491788396",

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A regular expression of `/365478$/` would provide the right filter.

Answer (score 3):

Regex will work but you won't be able to use an index for the query. I'd suggest storing the last 6 digits in a separate field, put an index on it and use that.

Comment: yeah that just makes it to big and if we need to move it from 6 to 7 we have to run it again

Comment: A [Regular Expression](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions) would work to find matches, but if you want the regex search to use an index on the barcode field, the match would have to be from the beginning of the string instead of the middle.  You could perhaps work around this by storing the substring of the barcode that you want to search, or by reversing the barcode when saving/fetching it.

Eg of using a regex in the JS shell:  `db.example.find({'barcode':/788396$/})`.

Comment: true you'd have to run it again but you'll come across lots of situations like this when dealing with mongodb. it's just one of the joys of working with a denormalized database :)

Answer (score 1):

This Works Well /$365478/ of course you can use regex but keeping it simple pays off.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex for this but you have to store the barcode reversed if you want to be able to use an index (only rooted regex can use an index, see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions)

If that is unpractical for you you will have to save the last X digits seperately and do exact matching. If your database is going to be relatively small you might be able to get away without indexing.

Answer (score 0):

the regex should be like this: `365478$`

using PHP for eg.

```
$regex = new MongoDB\BSON\Regex ( '365478$');
```